# Aplicação PHP não loga no app do facebook pelo localhost

Tags: php, aplicação-web, facebook

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação PHP que retorna a lista de amigos do usuário do facebook. Apesar de ter especificado o domínio e a URL do site no app do Facebbok que criei, recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> O URL informado não está na lista de liberação nas configurações de
>   OAuth do cliente: O redirecionamento falhou porque o URl usado não
>   está na lista de liberação nas configurações de OAuth do cliente do
>   aplicativo. Certifique-se de que o login de OAuth do cliente e web
>   esteja ativo e adicione todos os domínios do seu aplicativo como URls
>   válidos de redirecionamento de OAuth.

Verifiquei que usando o endereço localhost aparecia um erro, então, modifiquei as configurações do Xampp para mudar o alisa de localhost para testeleonardo.com. Aproveito para perguntar: seria possível eu retornar também todos os amigos de meus amigos? Ou isto seria uma violação de privacidade?

[image: Abaixo as configurações básicas do APP:]

[image: E as avançadas]

Comment: ja tentou colocar localhost?

Answer (score 4):

É bem simples de resolver isto.

Abra o `/etc/hosts (unix)` ou `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

Supondo que seu dominio seja testeleonardo.com, adicione esta linha:

```
127.0.0.1    local.testeleonardo.com
```

Então em seu teste, abra `local.testeleonardo.com` no seu navegador que deve funcionar.

Claro que você ainda poderia colocar nas configurações do app no facebook a url local da aplicação para teste.

Comment: Olá Otto! Já configuirei o arquivo hosts como vc citou e já acesso o localhost como testeleonardo.com. Isso funciona. O que não funciona é a autenticação no app do Facebook, que gera o erro.

Comment: Você configurou a url la no facebook tambem parceiro  ?

Comment: Configurei, como aparece nas imagens acima.

Comment: @LeoPinheiroDeSouza o site_url precisa estar igual ao hosts amigo. Lembra precisa adaptar a resposta.

Comment: Fiz a adapatação: local.testeleonardo em todos os locais. O erro persiste.

Comment: o erro continua sendo o mesmo ? @LeoPinheiroDeSouza

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34252/discussion-between-otto-and-leopinheirodesouza).

Comment: @LeoPinheiroDeSouza o teu <fb:registration redirect_uri="http://localhost/callback-fb-registered" /> esta apontando para o local correto ?

Comment: da uma olhada nisso http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667180/setting-up-facebook-login-on-localhost @LeoPinheiroDeSouza

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver esse problema é necessário excluir todas as informações de domínio.
[image: Configuração Básica]

E depois configurar a URL de destino do Login.
[image: Login do Facebook]

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguém ainda passe por esse problema. Na parde de "Login com o facebook"
dentro do Facebook Developers você deve procurar pelo campo:
"URIs de redirecionamento do OAuth válidos".

Ali você deve colocar o retorno do facebook, no meu caso usando o Laravel Socialite foi:
https://meudominio/login/facebook/callback.

Apos esse procedimento funcionou normalmente em produção.